# Why does not work subscribe() after combineLatest?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I started writing a simple script, but I ran into a problem, help me solve it.

Into the code creates 2 threads: player, walls:

```
const walls = Rx.Observable
    .range(1, 10)
    .map(() => {
        return {
            x: helper.randomIntFromZero(canvas.width - wallWidth),
            y: helper.randomIntFromZero(canvas.height - wallHeight)
        };
    })

const player = move.map(
    e => {
    const coords = { x: 0, y: 0 }

        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            coords.x -= (player.x <= 0) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            coords.y -= (player.y <= 0) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            coords.x += (player.x + player.width >= canvas.width) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
        }

        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            coords.y += (player.y + player.width >= canvas.height) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
        }

        return coords;
    }
)  
.startWith({ x: 0, y: 0 })
```

I subscribe to them at the same time:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest((player, walls) => {
    console.log(player, walls);
})
.subscribe((player, walls) => {
    console.log('player', player);
    console.log('walls', walls);
});
```

The problem is that the console.logs from the last piece of code are not output to the console.

[Live DEMO here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/raeh0w9g/3/)

Comment: You're not actually passing `player` and `walls` to `combineLatest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing observables to the `combineLatest`.

This is how you should do:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(player, walls)
```

And it will give you an array, so you should subscribe like this:

```
  .subscribe(([player, walls]) => {
    console.log('player', player);
    console.log('walls', walls);
  });
```